# How to install mod_dav_svn on Centos 5.5

Tags: svn, centos5

I'm trying to install `mod_dav_svn` on my server (Centos 5.5, Apache Apache 2.2.11, DirectAdmin 1.35.1 ), but no luck.

I'm using this tutorial: http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/Subversion#head-ae2d6fa671ad7ebd5d7835c6edbcd15dd2d73c4d

So, I'm trying in console:

```
# yum install mod_dav_svn subversion
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * addons: centos.bst.lt
 * base: centos.bst.lt
 * extras: centos.bst.lt
 * updates: centos.bst.lt
Excluding Packages in global exclude list
Finished
Setting up Install Process
No package mod_dav_svn available.
Package subversion-1.4.2-4.el5_3.1.i386 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
```

Why can't it find `mod_dav_svn`?

Also I tried:

```
#yum search mod_dav_svn
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * addons: centos.bst.lt
 * base: centos.bst.lt
 * extras: centos.bst.lt
 * updates: centos.bst.lt
Excluding Packages in global exclude list
Finished
Warning: No matches found for: mod_dav_svn
No Matches found
```

Nothing...

Answer (score 0):

When directadmin was installed, Apache was built from source and the exclusions were put in `yum.config` so that yum updates do not break Apache. If you want to install `mod_dav_svn`, use the direct admin custom build script.

This may be useful: "[SVN: Subversion + mod_dav_svn in custom Apache](http://www.directadmin.com/forum/showthread.php?t=30972)".

Answer (score 0):

It isn't so simple. In order to do this, you probably have to rebuild Apache, and you have to make sure you have APR and NEON libraries, and you have to make sure that all of your third party libraries are at the correct versions and work together nice and smoothly.

I've done this dozens of times, and it takes time, effort, sweat, tears, and lots and lots of frustration. And, I know what I'm doing. It can take me a few days to get everything working together.

There are two better solutions:

- Use a Linux distro that has Apache, mod_svn_dav, and Subversion all working together. I thought Centos should be one of them. I know that Fedora definitely has this.
- Install a third party solution like [Collab.net's Subversion Edge](http://www.collab.net/products/subversion). This is a pure open source Subversion package with the built in Apache server already configured and working. Everything you need. There are others who offer such a package -- some completely open source, and some Apache/Subversion packages with some proprietary graphical front ends.

[Ejder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3481187/368630) has pointed you in the direction of *rolling your own*, but be warned that this can differ from system to system. You need to parse output logs very carefully, and try to piece together various *clues* to get all of the various pieces working. My advice is that unless you are very familiar with building C code from scratch and using the GNU `configure` script, you are probably better off using a third party solution that already put all of the pieces together for you.